# Ubuntu upgrade from 11.04 to 11.10 fails to log in anyone anymore

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-11.10

After upgrading to Ubuntu 11.10 from 11.04, I can no longer login into any account on the system.

No matter what desktop manager I specify at the login screen, logging in always starts off loading the Nvidia drivers (goes to a black screen, shows Nvidia on the screen, etc.) and then immediately goes back to the login screen, for each account.  The system is completely unusable.  What steps can I take to correct this problem?

Comment: Have you checked similar posts on AskUbuntu?    
http://askubuntu.com/questions/65852/cannot-login-to-my-user-account    
http://askubuntu.com/questions/66482/cant-login-after-installing-11-10

Comment: Dennis you should post what was in those posts as an answer and I'll accept it.  I had to remove .Xauthority AND remove my .profile.  Double whammy.  Thanks for the awesomesauce.

Answer (score 1):

Visit [this](http://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/how-to-upgrade-from-ubuntu-11-04-to-ubuntu-11-10/)

***Note:** *It is advised to backup your system before performing the upgrade, since this is a Beta version and may have some functionality issues. Moreover, some new packages will be installed, existing packages will be upgraded and obsolete packages will be removed. This may result in the removal of some of your favorite applications.*

To start the upgrading process, Press ALT+F2, type update-manager –d and click Run.

This will open the Update Manager where an upgrade button will be visible with a message that the new Ubuntu release is available for upgrade. Click Upgrade to continue

Shortly after continuing, you will be asked to enter your password, after which the upgrade process will initiate. During the process, the unsupported packages will have to be removed. For that, a prompt will appear with a list of the packages that will be removed, installed and upgraded. Click Start Upgrade to continue.

The update can take a long period of time and the new packages may require a few hours to download (depending upon your internet connection speed).

After the upgrade is complete, you will be prompted to restart your computer for the changes to take effect. Once you log back in again the GUI changes should be enough to inform you that the upgrade was successful, however, if you would like to confirm your existing Ubuntu version, type the following in the Terminal:

lsb_release -a

Enjoy the new Ubuntu 11.10 experience.

Comment: Eh? The OP already upgraded to 11.10. Great explanation though